# how to display a spinner over a background image android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, background, spinner

I'm trying to add a spinner over a background image. I don't know why it doesn't display over this image. It display but under the image. I have to put it in the foreground.

Here is the spinner :

[image: the spinner]

And there is my background image :

[image: RelativeLayout]

```xml
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rl_sub_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cv_toolbar">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_weather_bg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/snow_bg_img">

                </ImageView>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If someone can give me something to try... It would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to gives a

```
android:translationZ="2dp"
```

to your spinner because if your image is upperside then your spinner at behind the image then you need to give the spinner `z-axis` more then the image.

Comment: it seems not good...